# proxy class for a private friend operator<<

Tags: c++

So yesterday I asked this question [private friend operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648705/private-friend-operator/15649548)
about how to make `operator<<` private for the class. I got a very good answer,
which worked exactly as I would like, but I have some additional questions about it.

First, I don't understand how come that the proxy class does not have to be friend of `private_printable` ? How is it possible that I have access to internal members of `private_printable` from within `operator<<` ?

Second, while playing with the code from answer, I wrote this:

```
operator proxy () const { return *this; }
```

At first it seemed OK to me and it even compiled, but when I run it and got a segfault
I realized that I haven't defined any constructor for the proxy class,
that would take `private_printable` as argument and thus allow the conversion.
So how is it possible that my code compiled, without even giving me any warnings ?

Then the third thing I did, was to give the proxy a constructor that had a reference
to `private_printable` as its argument (I did not make it explicit) instead of defining conversion operator.
Now all went fine except that it was again possible to call `operator<<`
on `private_printable`. But I am not really sure, why this happened.
Is it because of ADL ? I have some vague understanding about it, but I am not
sure of all its details. Anyways, the `proxy` class is private, so why would
ADL make any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `operator<<` can access members of `private_printable` because it's a `friend` of `private_printable`. It's not a `friend` of `proxy`.
2. `return *this` returns a `private_printable` object, which must be implicitly converted to `proxy`. How to convert `private_printable` to `proxy`? Call `private_printable::operator proxy ()`. But that's the function we're already in! The segfault is caused by stack overflow from infinite recursion. For what it's worth, an endless loop would be another possible outcome.
3. The non-`explicit` constructor is also a conversion function, serving the same purpose as `operator proxy`. ADL is sort-of involved, the same as if the `operator proxy` is used and no constructor. The solution of course is to make the constructor `explicit`. And the problem only occurs for that specific case, when the sole operand of the constructor is the proxied class.

The `proxy` class being a `private` member only matters when you explicitly name it. ADL can still find a function with a `proxy` argument, which then indirectly causes access to a conversion function, because use of a class type isn't affected by access qualification. Only name lookup is affected. Likewise, you can always use a `private` member type if you just have a `typedef` to it.